# JavaScript issue using Math.random and if statments

Tags: javascript

The issue I am having is I'm trying to get the alert to tell the person if the random number generated is in the ranges to be an A,B,C,D, or F. All that happens is it says all the numbers are F's not matter what.

```js
var grade = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1));
document.write(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1))
if (grade >= 90) {
  alert("A");
} else if (grade >= 80) {
  alert("B");
} else if (grade >= 70) {
  alert("C");
} else if (grade >= 60) {
  alert("D");
} else {
  alert("F");
}
```

Comment: Seems to work well...

Comment: Code appears to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/zrupygrm/ -- Although I noticed the original post initialized `grade` to a random number and then `document.write` (*shutters*) was also printing a random number which is confusing. I believe the intent was to showcase what the value of `grade` is to compare to the `alert`.

Comment: im still having issues were somtimes the alert will be wrong like the number is 12 and it will say A

Comment: It seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/wgw5nxpp/.  Remember, you're only going to get a grade A-D 40% of the time.  The rest of the time it will be F.  Run it a bunch of times and you can see the general distribution.

Comment: Problem is that `grade` is not equals to element which is written by `document.write(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1))`. Exact match will be when `document.write( grade )`

Comment: You have two random numbers, one is displayed using `document.write` and the other is used in your code. You probably wanted `document.write( grade )`.

Comment: Thanks to every one for the information i got it figured out you all are amazing thanks again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is that your not generating a random value properly.

Math.random() returns a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). Try using this statement.

```
var grade = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100));
```

Comment: Thanks i see what i did wrong using what u posted to get were i needed to be thanks a bunch

Comment: @WayneJenkins Yeah but people down-voted my answer. Please can you make it as the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're checking a different number than you're writing with `document.write` here:

```
var grade = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1));
document.write(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1))
```

This would need to be:

```
var grade = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1));
document.write(grade);
```

In order to accurately reflect what is happening.